# Black screen after updating to CUDA 10.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, cuda

After upgrading NVIDIA CUDA from 10.0 to 10.1, I'm now getting a black/blank screen right after login.

- Using Ubuntu 18.04.2
- Using the NVIDIA drivers included with the CUDA package.

There were no problems with CUDA 10.0.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed in Cuda 10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1048019/linux/black-screen-after-install-cuda-10-1-on-ubuntu-18-04/post/5321320/#5321320), set `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` and remove `quiet splash` in the GRUB kernel boot params. Here is the full process:

- Boot to recovery mode
- Start the root terminal
- Open `/etc/default/grub` with a text editor
- Add or edit: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nvidia-drm.modeset=1"`

  - (On a default installation, this replaces `"quiet splash"`)
- Save and exit
- Run `update-grub`
- Run `reboot`

This might not work for everyone, but it was a very clean fix for me.

Comment: Do not work for me. Kubuntu logo than black screen... Mouse cursor is moving